# Building XML using XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

The goal is to build the below XML in C#, writing it out via `StreamWriter` and pass it as part of HTTP Request.

```
<WEB_INTEGRATION_REQUEST> 
  <HTTP_HEADER_INFORMATION>
    <DEFINED_HEADERS>
      <HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER>
        <ItemNameType>RequesteDate</ItemNameType>
        <ItemValue>{TIME VALUE}</ItemValue> 
      </HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER>
      <HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER>
        <ItemNameType>AuthorizationValue</ItemNameType>
        <ItemValue>{EncryptedCredentials}</ItemValue> 
      </HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER>
    </DEFINED_HEADERS>
  </HTTP_HEADER_INFORMATION>
  <COLLABORATION>
    <TransactionID>0-A</TransactionID>
    <SequenceID>999</SequenceID>
  </COLLABORATION>
</WEB_INTEGRATION_REQUEST>
```

What's the best approach to write this XML? I have tried using `XDocument` (as seen below), but am getting confused in `XElements` and `XAttributes`:

```
private string BuildXML(string encodedCredentials)
{
    XDocument requestXMl = new XDocument( 
        new XElement("WEB_INTEGRATION_REQUEST",
            new XElement("HTTP_HEADER_INFORMATION",
                new XElement("DEFINED_HEADERS",
                    new XElement("HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER",
                            new XElement("ItemNameType","RequestDate"),
                            new XElement("ItemValue",_currentTime)
                                ),    
                        new XElement("HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER",
                            new XElement("ItemNameType","AuthorizationValue"),
                            new XElement("ItemValue",encodedCredentials)
                                )  
                              )
                           ),
            new XElement("COLLABORATION" ,
                new XElement("TransactionID", _transactionID),
                new XElement("SequenceID",_sequenceNumber)
                        )
                    )
            );
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we will be able to help you.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far, and give us some idea of what data you are trying to serialize?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you have not shown what you have tried and where exactly you are getting confused. Voting to close as unclear. You can [edit] your question to add the requested details to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument requestXMl = new XDocument( 
        new XElement("WEB_INTEGRATION_REQUEST",
            new XElement("HTTP_HEADER_INFORMATION",
                new XElement("DEFINED_HEADERS",
                    new XElement("HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER",
                            new XElement("ItemNameType","RequesteDate"),
                            new XElement("ItemValue",_currentTime)
                                ),    
                        new XElement("HTTP_DEFINED_REQUEST_HEADER",
                            new XElement("ItemNameType","AuthorizationValue"),
                            new XElement("ItemValue",encodedCredentials)
                                )  
                              )
                           ),
            new XElement("COLLABORATION" ,
                new XElement("TransactionID", transactionID),
                new XElement("SequenceID",sequenceID)
                        )
                    )
            );
```

thats how i did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to create a class and serialize it to XML. Using XmlElement attribute in your members to match your tag names, like in this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).